# Producing a raster plot in R

Tags: r, plot, raster, raster-graphics

I'm trying to produce a raster graph (like a hovmoller diagram) and was hoping someone might help. I've looked at the help with rasterVis and some others but can't seem to get their examples to suit my data, which probably needs transforming in some way that is eluding me. I've managed to create the plot but the fill values for the cells are not corresponding to the original data. I've copied a dput() file of an example of my data frame (hope this is the right way to do this). What I want is days of the year (DOY) along the x axis with a y axis of 48 rectangles (hour column in DF) above each DOY. These rectangles would represent half hourly intervals for each DOY and would be coloured according to their corresponding a value (qc column in DF) which is 0,1 or 2

So far I've come up with the following code but there seems to be a problem with the allocation of the z value (qc column) to the colour, I think the values are not lining up properly for some reason...

```
mcol <- c("green","blue","red")
x=unique(DF[,"DOY"])
y=unique(DF[,"hour"])
z=matrix(DF[,"qc"],nrow=length(unique(DF[,"DOY"])),
                     ncol=length(unique(DF[,"hour"])))
image(x,y,z, col=mcol,
  xlab="Day of Year 2012", 
  ylab="Hour of day",
  main="Hovmoller plot of 2012 qc flags",
useRaster=TRUE)
```

What seems to be happening is that the fill value matrix (z) is applied running along the bottom of the x axis first (left to right) then looping to the top whereas I need it to start at the bottom left hand corner and go up then loop left to right (hope that makes some sort of sense!)
My example data here only covers three days but the full dataset would be for an entire year (366  in 2012).
Thanks in advance for any help,

Jon

```
structure(list(DOY = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), hour = c(0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 
4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 11, 
11.5, 12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5, 15, 15.5, 16, 16.5, 17, 17.5, 
18, 18.5, 19, 19.5, 20, 20.5, 21, 21.5, 22, 22.5, 23, 23.5, 24, 
0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 
8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5, 
15, 15.5, 16, 16.5, 17, 17.5, 18, 18.5, 19, 19.5, 20, 20.5, 21, 
21.5, 22, 22.5, 23, 23.5, 24, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 
4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 
12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5, 15, 15.5, 16, 16.5, 17, 17.5, 18, 
18.5, 19, 19.5, 20, 20.5, 21, 21.5, 22, 22.5, 23, 23.5, 24), 
    qc = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("DOY", 
"hour", "qc"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -144L))
```

Comment: Something like `library(raster);plot(raster(t(z)))`?

Answer (score 4):

Close! Try something like this (x and y are generated by your code above):

```
library( sp )
r <- raster(nrows=length(y), ncols=length(x), xmn=min(x), xmx=max(x), ymn=min(y), ymx=max(y))
values(r) <- t(DF$qc)
spplot( r , cuts = 2 )
```

`spplot` from the package `sp` use lattice graphics and is extremely customisable according to your needs

[image]

Ok, `geom_tile` might be a better choice (until the number of raster cells gets large) if you want to be able to discern different cells:

```
p <-    ggplot( DF , aes(factor(DOY), hour ) ) + 
    geom_tile( aes(fill = factor(qc) ) , color = "#D9D9D9" ) + 
    scale_fill_brewer(name="QC", type = "div" , palette = "RdBu" )+
    scale_x_discrete( name = "Day" , expand = c(0,0) ) +
    scale_y_continuous( name = "Hour" , limits = c(0.5,24) , expand = c(0,0) , breaks = seq(0,24,2) )+
    coord_equal()
print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the replies but getting the same problem with misalignment of the qc values to the cells. As a test, if you alter all the qc values corresponding to DOY4 to 1 then there should be a vertical white line from ymin to ymax at the left of the plot, this does not happen. Somehow the matrix for the z values does not run in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Simon, yes I did want to discern the individual cells so your solution is ideal, thanks very much.

Comment: @JonP Ok great! You should now tick the green arrow either next to your answer or mine to indicate that this has answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

OK got this worked out now, and rather simply too...

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF,aes(DOY,hour,fill=qc))+geom_raster()
```

Sorry, that was rather more straightforward than I imagined. I would prefer the legend colours to be discrete rather than continuous but it's a minor detail. Thanks for your input.
Jon

Comment: ++ for being both communicative and informative in this thread.  Hope to see more of you around the R-community.

Answer (score 0):

The `hovmoller` function from the `rasterVis` package is designed
for 4D data (coordinates, numeric variable and a time
index). However, if I am not wrong, you need to plot an univariate
time series using a level plot.

Here I show an example with `lattice::levelplot`.

First, we define the data with a time index:

```
tt <- seq(as.POSIXct('2013-01-01'), by='hour', length=8760)
vals <- 1:24 - 12.5
myDF <- data.frame(vals, tt)
```

Next, we define two auxiliary functions to extract hour and day of
year from the time index:

```
hour <- function(x)as.numeric(format(x, '%H'))
DoY <- function(x)as.numeric(format(x, '%j'))
```

Then, we load the packages and define a theme with a sequential
palette from the `RColorBrewer` package:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
myTheme <- custom.theme(region=brewer.pal(n=10, 'RdBu'))
```

And finally, we are ready to display the data:

```
levelplot(vals ~ DoY(tt)*hour(tt),
          data=myDF,
          xlab='Day', ylab='Hour',
          par.settings=myTheme)
```

[image: levelplot result]

For a more complete solution, you may be interested in the
[`strip` function](http://metvurst.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/plotting-large-amounts-of-atmospheric_4.html)
of the
[`metvurst` package](http://metvurst.blogspot.com.es/2013/02/metvurst-now-package-repository-moved.html).